# List only parent and unpartition tables in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-11

I have lots of partitions for one table and there are other unpartitioned tables. If I do \d, it lists all the partitions and the list is very huge. I am looking for a way to list only unpartitioned and the parent tables. Is there any way to do the same?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no switch for `\dt` itself, but you can modify the underlying query:

```
SELECT n.nspname as "Schema",
  c.relname as "Name",
  CASE c.relkind WHEN 'r' THEN 'table' WHEN 'v' THEN 'view' WHEN 'm' THEN 'materialized view' WHEN 'i' THEN 'index' WHEN 'S' THEN 'sequence' WHEN 's' THEN 'special' WHEN 'f' THEN 'foreign table' WHEN 'p' THEN 'table' WHEN 'I' THEN 'index' END as "Type",
  pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(c.relowner) as "Owner"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE c.relkind IN ('r','p','')
      AND n.nspname <> 'pg_catalog'
      AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
      AND n.nspname !~ '^pg_toast'
      AND c.relpartbound IS NULL
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_inherits i
                      WHERE i.inhrelid = c.oid)
  AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

I added `AND c.relpartbound IS NULL` and the `NOT EXISTS` clause.

Comment: is it possible to create a macro for this query lets say \u, and it will display all the unpartioned and parent table?

Comment: Not without modifying `psql`'s source. You could create a view, but be warned that a view on system tables prevents `pg_upgrade`. It is better to write it as table function (and maybe create a view on the function).

Comment: "ERROR:  column c.relpartbound does not exist"; "psql (PostgreSQL) 9.1.20"

Comment: @rafz That can happen if you are using an old, unsupported version of PostgreSQL.